# не работает цикл while, хотя он должен работать

Tags: javascript, while

простой пример.

```js
var ask = prompt("enter your login");

while (ask != "Admin") {
  ask = prompt("enter your login");
  console.log(ask != "Admin"); // true
};

if (ask == "Admin") {
  alert("Hello, Admin");
}
```

специально ввожу не "Admin"
заходит в цикл 1 раз и если ввести не "Admin", уходит из цикла, хотя должен зациклится, пока не введешь "Admin"

Comment: Не воспроизводится описанная вами проблема.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать цикл do...while?

Answer (score 1):

А так?

```js
var ask = prompt("enter your login");

while(ask != "Admin") {
    ask = prompt("enter your login");
    console.log(ask != "Admin"); // true
}

if (ask == "Admin") {
    alert("Hello, Admin");
}
```

Comment: И в чем же отличие?

Comment: В отсутствии точки с запятой после `while` :).

Answer (score 0):

Еще, можно использовать другой цикл:

```
var ask;
do {
    ask = prompt("enter your login")
} while (ask != 'Admin')
```

Можно еще так:

```
while (true) {
    var ask = prompt("enter your login");
    if (ask == "Admin") {
        alert("Hello, Admin");
        break;
    } else {
          console.log(ask != "Admin");
      }
};
```

Прошу заметить, что Admin и admin это будет два разных логина